# Incorrect syntax near the keyword ''. When trying to Insert

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

Im trying to insert some data into a table which contains 3 FK

The Statement:

```
INSERT INTO Order (Datum,KundId,VaraId,FakturaId,Pris)
VALUES ('2002-1-1',1,1,1,100);
```

Gives:

```
Field Message
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Order'.
```

Comment: INSERT INTO [Order] (Datum,KundId,VaraId,FakturaId,Pris)
VALUES ('2002-1-1',1,1,1,100);

Comment: Order= a reserved word

Comment: This question was caused by a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: It is a “simple typographical error” for someone who knows the syntax of `INSERT INTO` command and has knowledge of `Key words` in sql server. For a newbie it is a proper legit question as it is not very easy to remember all the key words and their use in sql server. Therefore I believe it is a proper legit question and there is no need to downvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Order](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) is a reserved word. you need to escape it:

```
INSERT INTO [Order] (Datum,KundId,VaraId,FakturaId,Pris)
VALUES ('2002-1-1',1,1,1,100);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO [Order] (Datum,KundId,VaraId,FakturaId,Pris) VALUES ('2002-1-1',1,1,1,100);
```

Answer (score 0):

As SturtLC stated you used a reserved keyword for an identifier. When you use reserved keywords, spaces or special signs you need to delimit an identifier with a square brackets "[ ]" or " ".

Make sure that you always use [] when you use [delimited identifiers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), or even better always try to use [regular identifiers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx) and comply with the rules to avoid this kind of mistakes :)

Here a list of SQL Server [reserved keywords](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) for your future reference

Hope this gives you more insight on the issue